# Handle arbitrarily large numbers in python

Tags: python

I'm working through project Euler in order to further my programming skills. I've run into an interesting problem after revisiting my code for problem 3. Here's my code:

```
# prime numbers are only divisible by unity and themselves
# (1 is not considered a prime number by convention)
def isprime(n):
    '''check if integer n is a prime'''
    # make sure n is a positive integer
    n = abs(int(n))
    # 0 and 1 are not primes
    if n < 2:
        return False
    # 2 is the only even prime number
    if n == 2: 
        return True    
    # all other even numbers are not primes
    if not n & 1: 
        return False
    # range starts with 3 and only needs to go up the squareroot of n
    # for all odd numbers
    for x in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True


try:
    num = int(input('Please input a natural number:'))
except ValueError:
    print("Erm.. No. I need a number.")


mylist = []
check = True
newnum = num
i= 0


if isprime(num):
    print("%r is a prime number."%num)

else:
    while check:
        if isprime(i):
            if newnum % i ==0:
                mylist.append(i)
                print("%r is a prime factor of %r"%(i,num))
                newnum = newnum/i
                i=0

                if newnum ==1:
                    check = False

        if i==num:
            print("I guess the program broke.")
            check = False
        i+=1

    print ("The largest prime factor for %r is:"%num)
    print (max(mylist))
    print ("The list of prime factors for %r is:"%num)
    print (mylist)
```

So the problem I ran into is this code will run forever with numbers longer than 17 digits (I suspect anything higher than 144155188075855872 which is 2^59; it works with some 18 digit numbers and not others).

I found that if I input a number higher than that and check the answers with the Windows calculator, the answer will be very close to the whole number but it will have a decimal portion.

How do I change my function to accept and CORRECTLY compute arbitrarily large numbers? (preferably without using nonstandard libraries)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "correctly"? Do you use Python 2? Or 3?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I would presume Python 3.x from the `print` function and `int(input(` rather than `int(raw_input(`.

Comment: Probably so, but they are both valid statements in Python 2.

Answer (score 6):

Python integers are arbitrary-precision. The only thing I see in your code that might not work at high precision is this floating-point calculation:

```
int(n**0.5)+1
```

Since floats are approximate, you will get round-off error for numbers larger than what 64-bit floats can represent precisely (which happens around 2 to the 50-something). Instead, use integer calculations:

```
for x in itertools.count(3, 2):
    if x > n ** 2:
        break
    if n % x == 0:
        return False
```

Comment: Or did you mean `x**2 > n`?

Comment: You could use `takewhile` and `any` to get rid of the explicit loop. I'm not sure whether it would be more readable, or whether the small performance benefit would be even noticeable, but it might be.

Comment: From a quick test, the itertools version seems to be about 2% faster in CPython 3.3.2, 12% slower in PyPy 2.1.0b3/3.2.3, so… never mind, whichever one you find easier to read is better. Replacing `x**2 > n` with `x*x > n` and `n % x == 0` with `not n % x` (and, in the itertools version, `any(n % x == 0 for …)` with `not all(n % x for …)`) all make more difference.

Comment: So I tested it. I'm not sure what the problem is but it won't recognize anything past the first prime it tests. EDIT: @Robᵩ caught a mistake. After fixing that and running it on the number 987654321987654321, it still claims that 29 is a prime factor, which it is not.

Comment: Check your program with 987654321987654321 and [Wolfram's](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+987654321987654321) answer.